# Redirect after executing code

Tags: php, javascript, html, redirect

I want this PHP code to redirect to the previous page and refresh automatically...
I understand that with JavaScript I can go history back but it won't refresh.
Please help.

My code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","db_name");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

//post result to db
$result_set = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT points FROM total WHERE id = 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set);
$old_total = $row['points'];
$new_total = $old_total + $_REQUEST['total'];
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE total SET points = $new_total WHERE id = 1");
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: yea sorry, JAVASCRIPT

Answer (score 3):

Get the url in a session, when you want to redirect, just use that url and redirect the user and unset the session var

```
//Track this on the page you want to redirect your code
$_SESSION['prev_url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

On the next page use this

```
//When you want to redirect to previous page
header('Location: '.$_SESSION['prev_url']);
exit;
```

Be sure you are declaring `session_start()` at the top of the page

Comment: I used this code but i still get the same error
`redirecting not properly` whats the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

To redirect with php:

```
<? header("location: http://.........."); ?>
```

Please note that before this instruction you mustn't print html, if some html is printed your header will not be sent

Comment: it doesn't matter, it has to be used before any html output

Answer (score 0):

add

```
header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript code :

- forward: `window.history.go(+1)`
- backward: `window.history.go(-1)`

or jquery code:

- forward: `history.go(1);`
- backward: `history.go(-1);`